# Sylius customer and products relations

Tags: sylius

I need to know if sylius have support for that an customer can create your own products.

The model of my project is: a customer can create and sale your own products, and can to consump products that was created by other customers.

I see that i can create a rol and to add the permissions to an customer to make manage a product, but this solution show me all products that other customers can to create, that is, I not have a filter by customer.

I need to know if that is possible to make that with sylius of any way (config, overwriting an entity)?

Comment: Try exploring the channels, you could link a customer to a channel, then a customer could manage the products in his channel but could buy in every other channel.

Comment: thanks for the comment  !! , i will try your suggestion

Comment: Check ChannelContext.php, Sylius sets channel based on subdomain, but you can modify behaviour to base it on customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius doesn't support out of the box this solution, but it is possible to build product of that kind. I worked on one project similar to Etsy on some previous version of Sylius (two year ago) and we achived this quite easily. You will need to write a lot of your custom logic but it is possible. Let me know if you need help in developing this, I am sure we can help.