# Sylius in multi vendor product catalog mode

Tags: sylius

I need to build a product catalog. I don't need any orders and so on, just a list of products with prices. But...the main idea - allow different stores to add their products. So stores managers need to be able register in shop and see the list of ONLY theirs products and CRUD operations over them. Should I use sylius channels for this or I should create store entity, link products and users to store and somehow filter by this parameters on backoffice side?

I saw slightly similar question here:
[Sylius customer and products relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529528/sylius-customer-and-products-relations)

But I don't fill like channels are proper way for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channel are not the right solution.

Each channel should represent a separate platform where you offer your products to the customer, eg a channel is a `website`, `mobile devices`, `wearable devices`, `printed catalogue maybe?`
Each channel could have unique needs and limitations, but should in a way represent the same Domain Model.

The right solutions is with adding shop entity and creating the association with users and products as you described.

The is an feature request issue for this here: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/321

Also see there the last comment by codebakery-ch, that he made some progress on the feature and got some [initial commit](https://github.com/codebakery-ch/Sylius/commit/4dae38c1e7ef67b4d57e424dc205fa4b8dd9a02f)

So you can also try to contact him and help out or build upon his code.